# How do I enable print statement catching in pylint?

Tags: python, pylint

I have a file p.py which has a single line:

```
print('hello')
```

I run pylint (2.6.0) with:

```
pylint p.py --enable=E
```

all I get is:

```
************* Module p
p.py:1:0: C0304: Final newline missing (missing-final-newline)
p.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Your code has been rated at -10.00/10 (previous run: -10.00/10, +0.00)
```

How do I get pylint to throw E1601?

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: both 3.7 and 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger this error you'd need to be running Python 2.x and use a print statement instead of the print function

Print statements were the only option in early releases of Python 2.x. It was only with the decision to replace them with print functions in Python 3, that print functions were added to Python 2.6.

```py
# Print statement, only works in Python 2.x
print 'hello'

# Print function, Python >= 2.6
print('hello')
```

Pylint won't emit E1601 when running Python >= 3.0. In Python 3 using a print statement isn't a stylistic error it's a syntax error. My best guess why E1601 exists is to encourage Python 2 developers to use Python 3 features when possible so that their code is more portable.

Comment: This is very helpful, is there a way to catch prints in 3+?

Comment: Why are you trying to "catch prints"? Pylint only reports print statements in Python 2.x because using print functions makes the code more consistent with Python 3.x code.

Comment: To encourage logging rather than printing for example. We generally want to discourage prints in our code and rather log instead

Comment: I don't know of an automated way to detect them. I'd either write some custom pre-commit that greps for print statements, or check for them manually as part of code review.

Comment: Just FYI flake8-print does catch them! I guess you can use the 2 together

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't use `pylint` as the question asks, but I have used a simple bash one-liner in CI to catch calls to `print()`:

```
prints=$(grep -rn 'print('); [[ -z $prints ]] && echo 'no prints' || printf "found prints:\n$prints\n"
```

In the `||` path, you could `exit 1` to fail a CI run or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach for python3 is to use the combination of the builtins plugin and the bad-functions definition.

under `[MASTER]` section:

`load-plugins=pylint.extensions.bad_builtin`

and then under `[BASIC]`:

`bad-functions=print,exec` # also good to check for exec`